# Maven - Jmeter integration issues

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

We are currently in process of integrating Maven to Jmeter in one of our project and facing issues with result analysis.

For result analysis, we have included “jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin“ in the project POM.xml to PASS/FAIL the maven build based on the pre-defined throughput threshold condition.

Problem Statement :

The maven build skips the result analysis and build is successful irrespective of the throughput threshold set. (i.e. the maven build is successful even when the throughput is not met) .

Has anyone worked on Jmeter-maven integration or have faced similar issues, please let me know.

Below are the versions which we used for integration.

Maven -  3.3.3
Jmeter - 3.2
jmeter- maven-plugin  – 2.7.0
jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin – 1.0.6

Also is there any plugin available for build PASS/FAIL based on the response times?

Appreciate quick response.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that your configuration is not compatible with what `jmeter-analysis-maven-plugin` expects and I'm afraid no one will be able to help unless you provide your `pom.xml` file and `.jtl` results file (at least partial).

As alternatives you can consider the following options:

1. [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) has `jmeter-check-results` goal, so you can mark Maven build as failed if there are sample result failures:

   ```
   <execution>
       <id>jmeter-check-results</id>
       <goals>
           <goal>results</goal>
       </goals>
   </execution>
   ```
2. If you have [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) somewhere in your intranet you can consider adding your test under continuous integration pipeline so you will be able to use [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) which can mark the build as failed basing on various thresholds
3. And last but not least, you can kick off your test via [Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) tool which naturally supports JMeter tests and has powerful [Pass/Fail Criteria](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) subsystem so you will be able to run JMeter test using [Maven Exec Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) and Taurus will return a non-zero exit code in case of pass criteria not met causing build failure.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for quick response.